# MongoDB Connection to Meteor App

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, nosql

i am new to NOSQL databases and i had to deploy a solution by GIT and then install node js and MONGO DB and METEOR to run it . But i have an issue:

Mongo runs on port 3001 and Meteor runs on port 3000. I open a terminal and run mongod --config "path of my config file" which is the following

```
net:
bindIp:
port: 3000
storage:
dbPath: "\\dump\\meteor"
security:
authorization: "enabled"
```

Then on an another terminal i run mongo : and i have connecting to test 
then i do show dbs - use meteor and i see all the datas that are stored in my meteor db , means it is not empty

Then i open another command line and run the meteor project using meteor run --port 3000 or 3001 (i tried both)

Now i have the login page but when i enter my login infos it shows no reaction and no error

Please can you help?

Comment: Can anyone please answer? All i had is a minus one!!!!

Comment: Hi Ahmed, your question is a bit unclear, is the problem that the login page of your app doesn't work? Are you getting any errors on the browser console or terminal running meteor? - And don't worry about the random downvote, there are always lazy people that don't want to help improve a question. I'll happily counter it when this question is up to SO standards :)

Comment: @FredStark Thank you first of all for your interest, and sorry for making the question a bit unclear . In fact yes, the login page doesn't work i am connected to the ports , i see datas by mongo and still no errors. It's like meteor can't reach the database Mongo i guess

Comment: Try changing your mongo port to `3001`. To run your meteor application in the default port (which is 3000) you can simply type `meteor` while in the application's root folder in the terminal. No need for the extra `run --port 3000` unless you need to specify a different port. Mongo will automatically run on 3001 if your meteor application is on 3000 (if it was 4000 then mongo would be 4001). I'm suspecting that the issue is a conflict between the mongo server when initializing meteor (which is 3001) and the configuration you've set which is 3000.

Comment: I think it's very unlikely to be a mongo connection error (These would be *very* loud in the terminal), but this will take further debugging to know. Can you provide more information about your login page and application structure?

Comment: Actually, debugging this might be easier if you posted over in the Meteor forums: http://forums.meteor.com/